# Accordion doesn't work in Bootstrap 4 collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

https://fiddle.jshell.net/8v72rtxb/

I have the following code.

```
  <div class="menu-horizontal container">
    <div class="row menu-container" id="menu">
      <div class="col-md-3 menu-item">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed collapse-toggle" data-parent="#menu" href="#studies-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Studies
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="studies-collapse">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              Something...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 menu-item">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed collapse-toggle" data-parent="#menu" href="#research-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Research
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="research-collapse">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              Something...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I have no idea why data-parent doesn't work though. Expand one collapse div doesn't close the other collapse. I tried to copy the code from the example of bootstrap, but it still doesn't work.
Also in my project, I include `jquery.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`. I have checked some other questions, they said that `bootstrap.min.js` might have been included twice. But should that be the case?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured a workaround for this. Even without using the `data-parent` attribute.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/zyd1vL4o/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        $('.collapse').collapse("hide")
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you it helped for me as well in bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

Once go through this [jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8v72rtxb/7/)

And here is html code,

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Studies
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-block">
        <div id="studies-collapse">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Study Guides
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Counselling and Instructions
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Student Laboratory
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Student Exchange
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Post‐graduate studies
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Theses
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Exams
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Research
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="card-block">
        <div  id="research-collapse">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Study Guides
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Counselling and Instructions
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Student Laboratory
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Student Exchange
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Post‐graduate studies
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Theses
                </a>
                <a href="" class="menu-subitem">
                    Exams
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can downvoter comment on mistake, so that I can improve my answer, please ?

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I am still figuring out why my setup doesn't work. If I copied your code to my jsfiddle, it doesn't work...

Comment: I noticed this is because of your bootstrap js you used, I replaced it with other js and then I placed bootstrap's site example html in jsfiddle, it worked, and then I mapped your html into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```html
<div class="menu-horizontal container">
    <div class="row menu-container" id="menu">
        <div class="col-md-3 menu-item">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" data-target="#studies-collapse" href="#studies-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="studies-collapse">
                Studies
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="studies-collapse" data-parent="#menu">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        Something...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 menu-item">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" data-target="#research-collapse" href="#research-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="research-collapse">
                Research
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="research-collapse" data-parent="#menu">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        Something...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse';
```

Include this in your file and the collapse should work.

Answer (score -1):

If its not closing, then you might not be properly linking to to your bootstrap js. You shouldn't need to add anything extra.
check for the following js files:

- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap.bundle.min.js

If you're creating a bootstrap theme then in the functions do this:
  `wp_register_script( 'write your theme name here', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );`